# Intellij Idea 14 on Arch Linux opening to grey screen

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, java-8, archlinux, intellij-14

I am trying to run Intellij Idea 14 on my Macbook which I have loaded with Arch Linux. I have installed both Idea and the Oracle JDK8 installed from AUR.

When I run idea.sh, the splashscreen shows up and after it finishes loading it opens to [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92ROm.jpg).

Here is idea.log:

```
2015-10-29 17:02:33,298 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2015-10-29 17:02:33,312 [     14]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: IntelliJ IDEA (build #IC-141.2735.5, 22 Sep 2015 00:00) 
2015-10-29 17:02:33,312 [     14]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Linux (4.2.3-1-arch, amd64) 
2015-10-29 17:02:33,312 [     14]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.8.0_66-b17 (Oracle Corporation) 
2015-10-29 17:02:33,312 [     14]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 25.66-b17 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM) 
2015-10-29 17:02:33,314 [     16]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xbootclasspath/a:./../lib/boot.jar -Xms128m -Xmx750m -XX:MaxPermSize=350m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=225m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Djb.vmOptionsFile=./idea64.vmoptions -XX:ErrorFile=/home/noah/java_error_in_IDEA_%p.log -Djb.restart.code=88 -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC14 -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel 
2015-10-29 17:02:33,341 [     43]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library loaded (64-bit) in 27 ms 
2015-10-29 17:02:33,424 [    126]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - WM detected: bspwm 
2015-10-29 17:02:34,174 [    876]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 29 plugins initialized in 612 ms 
2015-10-29 17:02:34,174 [    876]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: Android Support (10.1.1.0), Ant Support (1.0), Bytecode Viewer (0.1), CVS Integration (11), Copyright (8.1), Coverage, Eclipse Integration (3.0), EditorConfig (1.0), Git Integration (8.1), GitHub, Gradle, Groovy (9.0), I18n for Java, IDEA CORE, IntelliLang (8.0), JUnit (1.0), Java Bytecode Decompiler (0.1), JavaFX (1.0), Maven Integration, Plugin DevKit (1.0), Properties Support, Subversion Integration (1.1), Task Management (1.0), Terminal (0.1), TestNG-J (8.0), UI Designer, XPathView + XSLT Support (4), XSLT-Debugger (1.4), hg4idea (10.0) 
2015-10-29 17:02:34,790 [   1492]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=200; buffer=10; max=739246080 
2015-10-29 17:02:34,814 [   1516]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Starting file watcher: /usr/share/intellijidea-ce/bin/fsnotifier64 
2015-10-29 17:02:34,822 [   1524]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Native file watcher is operational. 
2015-10-29 17:02:35,539 [   2241]   INFO - lij.diagnostic.DebugLogManager - Set DEBUG for the following categories: [] 
2015-10-29 17:02:35,977 [   2679]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342 
2015-10-29 17:02:36,557 [   3259]   INFO -                  TestNG Runner - Create TestNG Template Configuration 
2015-10-29 17:02:36,622 [   3324]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 20 project components initialized in 409 ms 
2015-10-29 17:02:36,622 [   3324]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 0 module(s) loaded in 0 ms 
2015-10-29 17:02:36,865 [   3567]   INFO - pl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl - 83 application components initialized in 2621 ms 
2015-10-29 17:02:36,870 [   3572]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - App initialization took 4204 ms 
2015-10-29 17:06:05,892 [ 212594]   INFO - org.jetbrains.io.BuiltInServer - web server stopped 
2015-10-29 17:06:05,893 [ 212595]   INFO - Types.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl - FileTypeManager: 0 auto-detected files
Elapsed time on auto-detect: 0 ms 
2015-10-29 17:06:05,907 [ 212609]   INFO - dea.ddms.adb.AdbService$Ddmlib - DDMLib terminated 
2015-10-29 17:06:05,907 [ 212609]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - START INDEX SHUTDOWN 
2015-10-29 17:06:05,927 [ 212629]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - END INDEX SHUTDOWN 
2015-10-29 17:06:05,927 [ 212629]   INFO - stubs.SerializationManagerImpl - START StubSerializationManager SHUTDOWN 
2015-10-29 17:06:05,927 [ 212629]   INFO - stubs.SerializationManagerImpl - END StubSerializationManager SHUTDOWN 
2015-10-29 17:06:06,002 [ 212704]   WARN - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Watcher terminated with exit code 0 
2015-10-29 17:06:06,003 [ 212705]   INFO - newvfs.persistent.PersistentFS - VFS dispose started 
2015-10-29 17:06:06,003 [ 212705]   INFO - newvfs.persistent.PersistentFS - VFS dispose completed 
2015-10-29 17:06:06,007 [ 212709]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE SHUTDOWN ------------------------------------------------------
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which edition did you install?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is most likely due to your window manager, bspwm. If you set the following environment variable before starting IntelliJ, it should work.

`_JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1`

Comment: This apparently is also applicable to xmonad. Thanks!

Comment: And to sway, we should probably ask Intellij to fix this no?

Comment: Also fixed for DWM. Thanks!

Comment: Even though I've added that, I still get the grey box and nothing else. I'm on Arch, running Rider 2021.3.2

Comment: Works with DWM and Picom :D

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As @thomas pointed out, the missing environment variable is causing this issue

Here're the steps to do that.

- Copy this -> `_JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1`

If you have `nano` installed:

- Run `sudo nano /etc/environment` on terminal and enter the password if prompted
- Scroll to the bottom
- Paste by pressing `Shift + Insert`
- Save by pressing `Ctrl + O` and confirm the path with `Enter`
- Quit by pressing `Ctrl + X`

If you have `vim` installed:

- Run `sudo vim /etc/environment` on terminal and enter the password if prompted
- Scroll to the bottom
- Enter insert mode by pressing `i`
- Paste by pressing `Shift + Insert`
- Exit the insert mode by pressing `Esc`
- Save and exit by typing `:wq` and `Enter`

The error should be resolved. This is apparently documented along with Android Studio on the [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/android#Android_Studio)